# Official information/data source for funds identified by ISIN

Tags: online-data-source

I found funds that have a ISIN/WKN identifier, for example this one:

- "Canada Life Aktien Chance Verantwortung II" (WKN: CLE038 / ISIN: IE00B3YZ4982)

but apart from some third-party websites [1,2] and the offering company [3], there seems to be no official instance that provides this information. As this fund seems to be registered in Ireland, I tried to find it in the Irish Stock Exchange, but had no luck.

**So my question is whether there is an official data source (e.g., stock exchange) that tells me the value of this fund and how to find it. 
As a bonus, it would be nice if there would be a good (best-case also official) source for automatically downloading/extracting this data.**

As I am new to the finance area, I might have missed some details you need to properly answer. Please feel free to ask and I will try to provide the missing information to the best of my knowledge.

Thank you a lot in advance!

[1] https://www.finanzen.net/fonds/canada_life_aktien_chance_verantwortung_ii

[2] https://www.boerse-online.de/fonds/canada-life-aktien-chance-verantwortung-ii

[3] http://canada-life.fondsintern.de/Popup.php?isin=IE00B3YZ4982#

Answer (score 1):

The first two characters of ISIN show the country in which the issuing company is headquartered.  It doesn't imply that the financial instrument is stock-exchange-listed in that country.

Regarding IE (Ireland), in general, many companies that operate in the EU are headquartered there for tax reasons.

Note that parent company of Canada Life Ireland (Great-West Lifeco) acquired Irish Life in 2013, and has rebranded the entire business Irish Life.  You can find more on their web site here:
https://www.irishlife.ie/investments/fund-centre